# Autolayout multiline UILabel in subview; height incorrect on first layout pass

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uilabel

I've read many of the questions and tutorials on how to get multiline autolayout labels working and several of the solutions seem to work, but only the second time I display my subview.

I have a full screen view controller that has a container vertically centered in it. Subview controllers are swapped in and out of the container, and the container height stretches/shrinks to accommodate the height of the given subview. Most of my subviews have a fixed height, but one has a label whose height (and therefore the subview height) is based off the label content. All subviews have constraints from top to bottom. I have tried:

1. Using a custom `UILabel` that sets its `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` in the `layoutSubviews` method
2. Using a custom `UILabel` that updates its constraints when the bounds are set and sets its `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` when the constraints are updated
3. Setting the `UILabel`'s `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` in the subview controller's `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method and calling `layoutIfNeeded`

All of these methods work, but only the *second* time the subview is displayed. The label is always truncated the first time the subview is displayed. I can get the label to never truncate by setting the greater than or equal to height constraint to a large enough value, but that is not what I want because then my subview no longer appears vertically centered when there is less text because of the extra padding.

So, how do I get the subview to update it's height correctly the first time it is displayed?

Edit:

Here's the subview I'm working with:
[image]

And here's the container in the parent view:
[image]

Comment: Could you please share some images of the Views?

Comment: What is the value of your UILabel's .numberOfLines property?